# Run as administrator dialog doesn't show on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

When I try to run any application that requires be run as administrator, Windows tries to show a message box asking for permission. The problem is that dialog doesn't appear.

It looks like that the dialog is lost somewhere out of my screen resolution. My PC freezes, and I just can see my desktop background behind. Ctrl + Alt + Del responds and goes to Task Manager, however it closes the dialog (I can briefly see the dialog after that command).

I tried to change the permission setting on "UAC" but it asks for permission to do that, so I'm stuck.

PS: I can't capture my screen because the "Printscreen" command doesn't respond in this context. I'm using a laptop without additional screens.

Comment: The UAC box is appearing if it's loading the Secure Desktop, as you can't get one without the other if the UAC settings in Control Panel are set to that option, so it's likely showing on one of the other screens, depending on how you have them configured.  What happens if you unplug the laptop from the additional screens (it should cause the UAC permissions box to display on the laptop's screen)? To resolve, you'll need to figure out what it is about your extended desktop that's causing the issue, such as an unstable resolution or resolution that's cutting off a portion of the extended desktop

Answer (score 0):

**First off, for someone coming by this, restart the PC first. This could just be an error that occurred during boot and a reboot may fix it. Continuing on from here....**

If it is appearing that the dialog is out of view you could try scanning the disk for errors and/or reinstalling a few drivers. Unfortunately because of this error you cannot open CMD in Admin mode to scan the disk, so I'd try drivers first.

***REINSTALLING DEVICE DRIVERS***

- List item
- Click the search icon bottom left and search "device manager"
- Look for "Monitors". Unfold the list and you'll see a few components
- Right-click the component and press "Uninstall Device"
- Click "Delete the driver software for this device", and "Uninstall"
- *Wait for completion*
- Look for "Display Adapters". Unfold the list.
- Right-click the component in the unfold list and press "Uninstall Device"
- Click "Delete the driver software for this device", and "Uninstall". You'll probably see the screen flicker a few times
- *Wait for completion*
- Now restart the PC and it will automatically search for the new drivers and install them. Do this while the PC is connected to an internet connection

Deleting the drivers and restarting causes Windows to research for the drivers needed to make the GPU and displays sync properly. If one of these were corrupt then it could cause issues like the OP has described.

Hope this fixes your issue!
                           ~TJ

Comment: It worked once. However, the problem came back after some minutes. I tried to redo the procedure in order to change my UAC settings but it didn't work on the second try. I will keep trying.

Comment: The issue the OP is experiencing is neither due to graphics drivers, or any driver, nor a disk error.  I'm unsure why this conclusion was reached.  The issue is resultant from an unsupported extended desktop resolution or a resolution that's cutting off a portion of the extended desktop/alignment image issue on the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a work-around:**

When the dialog is expected, but not visible,

- Press [Windows] + L to lock the computer.
  The process of locking will briefly show the dialog.
- Unlock the computer
- Position the mouse where the YES-button should be
- With the mouse in one hand and the other on the keyboard...
- Lock the computer, being ready to click the button when the dialog appears
- Click the [YES]-button
- Unlock

Now the requested program starts in administrator-mode.